# Why does LWC map behave differently when put in lightning communities?

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, lightning-map

I have this map component that shows the info window when one clicks on a marker but the nothing happens when I put the same component in communities. Is there an extra configuration step I need to do?

The zoom buttons aren't clickable either.

Here is the map in developer org[image: correct map]

The same map in communities -marker is not even clickable
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: please check the developer tools/console for any warning/errors when you click on the marker.

Comment: The marker is not clickable. The hand pointer does not show on hovering over the marker. No errors/warnings in the console.

Comment: and when you load the page, any console errors/warnings ?

Comment: no errors on loading the page.

Comment: The markers are loading ok. Its just that they are not clickable.

Comment: DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for https://parxisconsulting2-dev-ed.livepreview.salesforce-communities.com/auraFW/javascript/1617168642000/aura_prod.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Comment: that shows in the console but I see that often so I don't know if its what you were asking earlier

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue.

The map does not work in preview mode but after publishing the site the map is now clickable. Such a small thing!

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is an extra step! You need to allow the `maps.a.forceusercontent.com` in your CSP settings in Experience Builder.

> lightning-map loads content from the Salesforce domain maps.a.forceusercontent.com in an iframe. Allow `maps.a.forceusercontent.com` if you use this component in your own domain and you use the Content Security Policy frame-src directive, such as in Experience Builder sites or Lightning Out. For more information, see [Content Security Policy in Experience Builder sites](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.networks_security_csp_allow.htm&type=5).

Pic here in case the link gets broken:
[image]

Source is [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-map/documentation)

Comment: Thanks Casper. I already had that set up. I had used.. https://*.forceusercontent.com

Comment: I am wondering if I need to define a property in target config in the meta-xml file. But I am not sure what I would use to define the property.